# Proof of the Sylvester's criterion

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, proof-explanation

I am self-learning basic optimization algorithms from `Introduction to Optimization` by Chong and Zak. Linear Algebra isn't exactly my forte, so I had a couple of questions (*soft notes are in italics*) on the proof of Sylvester's criterion that's used to test whether a given matrix $Q$ is positive definite is correct. I reproduce the proof for completeness followed by my questions.

**Theorem.** A quadratic form $\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x}$, $Q=Q'$, is positive definite if and only if the North-west principal minors of $Q$ are positive.

***Proof***.

---

*Intuitively, I understand that a quadratic form $\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x}$ is a polynomial in $x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n$ of degree at most $2$. What we are interested in is, to transform the coordinates (find a new basis) in way, that we can complete the squares and show that the quadratic form is positive definite.*

---

To this end, consider a quadratic form $f(\mathbf{x})=\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x}$, where $Q = Q'$. Let $\{e_1,e_2,\ldots,e_n\}$ be the standard basis for $\mathbf{R}^n$ and let

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x} = x_1 e_1 + x_2 e_2 +\ldots x_n e_n
\end{align*}

Let $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$ be another basis for $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then, any vector $\mathbf{x}$ is represented in the new basis as

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}_{old} &= \tilde{x_1} v_1 + \tilde{x_2} v_2 +\ldots \tilde{x_n} v_n\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}v_1 &v_2 &\ldots & v_n \end{bmatrix}\cdot \begin{bmatrix}
\tilde{x_1}\\
\tilde{x_2}\\
\tilde{x_3}\\
\vdots\\
\tilde{x_n}
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=V\mathbf{\tilde{x}}_{new}
\end{align*}

Accordingly, the quadratic form can be written as:

\begin{align*}
\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x} &= (V\mathbf{\tilde{x}})'Q (V\mathbf{\tilde{x}})\\
&=\mathbf{\tilde{x}}'V'QV\mathbf{\tilde{x}}\\
&=\mathbf{\tilde{x}}'\tilde{Q}\mathbf{\tilde{x}}
\end{align*}

Note that $\tilde{q}_{ij}=\langle v_i,Qv_j\rangle$. Our goal is to determine the conditions on the new basis $\{v_1,v_2,\ldots,v_n\}$, such that $\tilde{q}_{ij}=0$ for all $i \ne j$.

We seek the new basis in the form (*the right hand side below are the entries of the change of basis matrix $V$*):

\begin{align}
v_1 &= \alpha_{11} e_1 \\
v_2 &= \alpha_{21} e_1 + \alpha_{22} e_2 \\
v_3 &= \alpha_{31} e_1 + \alpha_{32} e_2 + \alpha_{33} e_3 \\
\vdots\\
v_n &= \alpha_{n1}e_1 + \alpha_{n2}e_2 + \ldots + \alpha_{nn}e_n
\end{align}

Observe that for $j=1,\ldots,i-1$, if

\begin{align}
\langle v_i, Qe_j \rangle = 0
\end{align}

then

\begin{align}
\langle v_i, Qv_j \rangle = 0
\end{align}

Our goal then is to determine the coefficients $\alpha_{i1},\alpha_{i2},\ldots,\alpha_{ii}$, $i=1,\ldots,n$ such that the vector

\begin{align}
v_i = \alpha_{i1}e_1 + \alpha_{i2}e_2 + \ldots+\alpha_{ii}e_i
\end{align}

satisfies the $i$ relations

\begin{align*}
\langle v_i, Qe_j \rangle &= 0, \quad j=1,\ldots,i-1\\
\langle e_i, Qv_i \rangle &= 1
\end{align*}

*Basically, this is being done to ensure that we end up with the diagonal matrix $\tilde{Q}$*.

In this case, we get

\begin{align*}
\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}
\alpha_{11}& \ldots & 0\\
\vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
0 & \ldots & \alpha_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

---

*I guess, this can be elaborated as follows.*

\begin{align*}
\tilde{Q} &= V'QV\\
&= \begin{bmatrix}
v_1\\
v_2\\
v_3\\
\vdots\\
v_n
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
Qv_1 & Qv_2 & Qv_3 & \ldots & Qv_n
\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}
\langle v_1, Qv_1 \rangle & \langle v_1, Qv_2 \rangle & \langle v_1, Qv_3 \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_1, Qv_n \rangle \\
\langle v_2, Qv_1 \rangle & \langle v_2, Qv_2 \rangle & \langle v_2, Qv_3 \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_2, Qv_n \rangle \\
\langle v_3, Qv_1 \rangle & \langle v_3, Qv_2 \rangle & \langle v_3, Qv_3 \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_3, Qv_n \rangle \\
\vdots\\
\langle v_n, Qv_1 \rangle & \langle v_n, Qv_2 \rangle & \langle v_n, Qv_3 \rangle & \ldots & \langle v_n, Qv_n \rangle 
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

Now, the inner product
\begin{align}
\langle v_j, Qv_j \rangle &= \langle v_j, Q\sum_{i=1}^{j} \alpha_{ij}e_i \rangle\\
&=\langle v_j,Q \alpha_{1j} e_1 \rangle + \langle v_j,Q \alpha_{2j} e_2 \rangle + \langle v_j, Q \alpha_{j-1,j}e_{j-1} \rangle + \langle v_j,Q \alpha_{jj} e_j \rangle\\
&=0 + 0 + \ldots + \alpha_{jj}\\
&=\alpha_{jj}
\end{align}

Also, the inner product

\begin{align}
\langle v_1,Qv_2 \rangle &= Q\langle v_2,v_1 \rangle \\
&= \langle v_2, Q\alpha_{11}e_1 \rangle\\
&= 0
\end{align}

and

\begin{align}
\langle v_2,Qv_1 \rangle &= \langle v_2,Q\alpha_{11}e_1 \rangle \\
&= 0
\end{align}

---

For each $i=1,\ldots,n$, the $i$ relations above determine the coefficients $\alpha_{i1},\ldots,\alpha_{ii}$ in a unique way. Indeed upon subsituting the expression for $v_i$ into the equations above, we obtain a set of equations as follows:

\begin{align*}
\langle v_i, Qe_1\rangle &= 0\\
\langle v_i, Qe_2\rangle &= 0\\
\vdots \\
\langle v_i, Qe_{i-1}\rangle &= 0
\end{align*}

that is

\begin{align*}
\langle (\alpha_{i1},\alpha_{i2},\ldots,\alpha_{ii}), Qe_1\rangle &= 0\\
\langle (\alpha_{i1},\alpha_{i2},\ldots,\alpha_{ii}), Qe_2\rangle &= 0\\
\vdots \\
\langle (\alpha_{i1},\alpha_{i2},\ldots,\alpha_{ii}), Qe_{i-1}\rangle &= 0
\end{align*}

Now, $Qe_{s}$ is the $s$-th column of $Q$. So, the first $(i-1)$ equations become:

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{i1}q_{11} + \alpha_{i2} q_{21} + \ldots + \alpha_{ii}q_{i1} &= 0\\
\alpha_{i1}q_{12} + \alpha_{i2} q_{22} + \ldots + \alpha_{ii} q_{i2} &= 0\\
\vdots \\
\alpha_{i1}q_{1,i-1} + \alpha_{i2} q_{2,i-1} + \ldots + \alpha_{ii} q_{i,i-1} &= 0
\end{align*}

Finally,

\begin{align}
\langle e_i, Qv_i \rangle &= 1\\
\langle e_i, (\alpha_{i1}Qe_1 + \alpha_{i2}Qe_2 + \ldots + \alpha_{ii}Qe_i)\rangle &= 1\\
\alpha_{i1} e_i Qe_1 + \alpha_{i2} e_i Qe_2 + \ldots + \alpha_{ii}e_iQe_i &= 1\\
\alpha_{i1} q_{1i} + \alpha_{i2}q_{2i} + \ldots + \alpha_{ii}q_{ii}=1
\end{align}

The set of equations above can be expressed in the matrix form as

\begin{align*}
\begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \ldots & q_{1i} \\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \ldots & q_{2i} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
q_{i1} & q_{i2} & \ldots & q_{ii}
\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} 
\alpha_{i1}\\
\alpha_{i2}\\
\vdots \\
\alpha_{ii}
\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0 \\
0 \\
\vdots \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

---

**Question.** I noticed that my set of equations are the transpose of the matrix that the author uses above. Is this cool, as far as $Q = Q'$ ($Q$ is symmetric).

---

If the north-west principal minors of $Q$ do not vanish, then the cofficients $\alpha_{ij}$ can be obtained using the Cramer's rule. In particular,

\begin{align*}
\alpha_{ii} = \frac{1}{\Delta_i} det \begin{bmatrix}
q_{11} & q_{12} & \ldots & q_{1,i-1} & 0\\
q_{21} & q_{22} & \ldots & q_{2,i-1} & 0\\
\vdots  \\
q_{i1} & q_{i2} & \ldots & q_{i,i-1} & 1
\end{bmatrix} = \frac{\Delta_{i-1}}{\Delta_i}
\end{align*}

Note that, $q_{11} \alpha_{11} = 1$, so $\alpha_{11} = 1/q_{11} = 1/\Delta_1$

\begin{align}
\tilde{Q} = \begin{bmatrix}
\frac{1}{\Delta_1} & & & 0 \\
 & \frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2} & &\\
 &  & \ddots & \\
0 &  &  & \frac{\Delta_{n-1}}{\Delta_{n}}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}

In the new basis, the quadratic form can be expressed as a sum of squares.

\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\tilde{x}}'\tilde{Q}\mathbf{\tilde{x}} = \frac{1}{\Delta_1}\tilde{x}_1^2 + \frac{\Delta_1}{\Delta_2}\tilde{x}_2^2 + \ldots + \frac{\Delta_{n-1}}{\Delta_n}\tilde{x}_n^2
\end{align}

If all $\Delta_i > 0$, $i=1,\ldots,n$, then by the above argument, there is a basis such that the sum of the squares given by $\mathbf{x}'Q\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{\tilde{x}}'\tilde{Q}\mathbf{\tilde{x}} > 0$.

Comment: Did you mean Sylvest**e**r's criterion?

Comment: Typo corrected. Thanks.

Comment: I couldn't find a single question in your longread.

Comment: @VasilyMitch, I noticed that my set of equations are the transpose of the matrix that the author uses above. Is this cool, as far as $Q=Q′$ ($Q$ is symmetric)? Other than that, as I typed the proof on Math SE, I understood all of the details clearly. :D